# React loop through array and render instances of multiple child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to iterate over an array and assign fields to corresponding child components.
The way I am currently doing it looks like this:

```js
class CardExtension extends React.Component {   
    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
            { this.props.value }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```js
class Card extends React.Component {   
    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
            { this.props.title }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Once child components are defined and imported, I do push new instances of these classes to a completely new array:

```js
class CardContainer extends React.Component {   
    render() {
        var arr = [
                {
                    'id':1,
                    'title':'title',
                    'value':'test_value'
                }
            ]
        var elements=[];
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            elements.push(<Card title={ arr[i].value } />);
            elements.push(<CardExtension value={ arr[i].title } />);
        }
        return (
            <div> 
            {elements}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish the same using the following format

```js
class CardContainer extends React.Component {   
    render() {

        var arr = [
            {
                'id':1,
                'title':'title',
                'value':'test_value'
            }
        ]
        return (
            <div> 
                {arr.map((el, idx) => (
                    <Card title={ el.value } />
                    <CardExtension value={ el.title } />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

@update
The problem is that whenever I do use the latest solution, I do receive following error message: ***Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (39:24)***

Comment: aren't you iterating over arr ? where did stagesTasks come from?  you can just replace stagesTasks with arr and it would work

Comment: I have used wrong naming of the variables. It has been corrected now. `stagesTasks has been replaced with `arr`

Comment: if you are iterating with arr, please dont access it with this.arr . apart from that the code looks it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

export default class CardContainer extends React.Component {   
    render() {

        var arr = [
            {
                'id':1,
                'title':'title',
                'value':'test_value'
            }
        ]

        return (
            <div> 
                {arr.map((el, idx) => (
                    <Fragment>
                        <Card title={ el.value } />
                        <CardExtension value={ el.title } />
                    </Fragment>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message *"Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag"* means just that: the `<Card>` and `<CardExtension>` elements need to be wrapped in a parent tag.

Now, you probably don't want to wrap the elements in a `<div>` (since it would create unnecessary DOM nodes), but [React has a nifty thing called "Fragments"](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), letting you group elements without extra nodes.

Here is a working solution for your example, using the fragment short syntax:

```
class CardContainer extends React.Component {   
  render() {
    var arr = [{
      'id':1,
      'title':'title',
      'value':'test_value'
    }]

    return (
      <div>
        {arr.map((el, idx) => (
          <>
            <Card title={ el.value } />
            <CardExtension value={ el.title } />
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```